# No themes are shown when I recompile Gtk

Tags: ubuntu, gtk

I recompiled Gtk (I wanted to make a minor change to fix something that annoyed me), and I wanted to install it at `/usr/local`, so I didn't specify any prefix, I just used

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

When I do this, however, only a few themes are shown in lxappearance, and some of them don't work. There should be 20-30 themes if the standard lib at `/usr` is used.

How can I fix that? I assume maybe I need to compile some other package as well, since the Gtk lib would be looking at `/usr/local` for modules and themes and such.

I'm on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.

[image]

Comment: make a symbolic link to the actual themes dir from your install path. Give it a try...